# render bar chart with different colors in react native

Tags: react-native, d3.js, charts

[image]

I want to create bar chart having each bar different color with x-axis values. I have tried barChart from [react-native-svg-charts](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts#children).

Answer (score 3):

You can create the bar chart having each bar with different color using the **react-native-svg-charts** module using the **BarChart**. I have just created a bar chart with different color using the code below:-

you can provide the data with each different svg colors as below:-

```
    const data1 = [ 14, -1, 100, -95, -94, -24, -8, 85, -91, 35, -53, 53, -78, 66, 96, 33, -26, -32, 73, 8 ]
    .map((value) => ({ value }))
    const data2 = [ 24, 28, 93, 77, -42, -62, 52, -87, 21, 53, -78, -62, -72, -6, 89, -70, -94, 10, 86, 84 ]
        .map((value) => ({ value }))

    const barData = [
        {
            data: data1,
            svg: {
                fill: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)',
            },
        },
        {
            data: data2,
            svg: {
                fill: 'red',
            },
        },
    ]
```

Then you can use this bar data inside the bar chart so that you get 2 bars with different colors as red and blue.

```
        <BarChart
            yAccessor={({ item }) => item.value}
            style={{ height: 200 }}
            data={ barData }
            svg={{ fill: 'green' }}
            contentInset={{ top: 30, bottom: 30 }}
        >
            <Grid/>
        </BarChart>
```

Let me know if you still have any problem.
You can even find this example on the examples of the **react-native-svg-charts** on this [link](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/storybook/stories/bar-chart/with-multiple-data-sets.js).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please tell me how can i add that rectangle rendering monthly average message.

Comment: How to achieve this if we have dynamic data array coming from server and then need to bind that data values with array of colours available like const myColorScale = ['rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(0,0,255)'];